# Change property value don't take effect with asynchronous way in IIS

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, iis, .net-core

I have a DotNet Core 2 web api project, a singleton provider class that keep a property:

```
in Startup.cs
services.AddSingleton<TokenProvider>();

in TokenProvider:
public string TokenValue { get; private set; } = "initial value";
```

Also made a HostedService which update this property periodically.

```
in HostedService:
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await _tokenProvider.UpdateToken(cancellationToken);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600, cancellationToken);
    }
}

in TokenProvider:
public async Task UpdateToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TokenValue = "updated value";
}
```

Then made a controller to public this token value.

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    var tokenProvider = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(TokenProvider)) as TokenProvider;
    var tokenValue  = tokenProvider.TokenValue;
    return tokenValue;
}
```

In my local, I always get the value "updated value" every time when I start my project with command "dotnet run". But once I deploy to IIS, I got "initial value" for the first time, only can get expected value "updated value" from the second time.

I tried to make UpdateToken method synchronous:

```
in TokenProvider:
public void UpdateToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TokenValue = "updated value";
}
```

That always works well, got "updated value" every time.

The TokenProvider is singleton, why doesn't the property change immediately with asynchronous way in IIS?

Any suggestion or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: HTTP context is per thread.

Comment: I tried inject TokenProvider through Constructor, but also failed.